# Get part of the TItle in Wordpress with a function

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm struggling in creating a shortcode that will get part of the Page title.

I have already created (thanks to someone in StackOverflow...)

```
function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

but I need also to get part of the Title and it has to get only last chars:

Title: Assistenza Caldaie Vaillant

I need to get only **Vaillant** (Assistenza Caldaie is always the same).

Could someone help me?

Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the php function explode, which splits a string according to a delimiter. Then you have to return the last part of it.

```
function myshortcode_title(){

   $original_title = get_the_title();
   $title_array = explode(" ", $original_title);
   return end($title_array);

}

add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

Comment: It works fine if the brand after "Assistenza Caldaie" is composed by one word, but in case of a double word (like Olimpia Splendid) I get only last word (Splendid).Any suggestion?

Comment: Another solution would be to get all of the array values that are greater than 1, but if the first part of your title is always the same, the code you used is simpler and more effective :)

Answer (score 0):

After several searches and attempts here the code used:

```
function myshortcode_marca( ){
    return str_ireplace('Assistenza Caldaie ', '', get_the_title());
}
add_shortcode( 'marca', 'myshortcode_marca' );
```

Thanks Angelo_ml!